# finite subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$. Prove that there exists a matrix $A\in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $AGA^{-1}\subseteq U_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: You may want to take a peek here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176717/finite-subgroups-of-gln-mathbbc

Comment: see http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1365244_a_finite_subgroup_of_gl_nmathbbc