# Question about definiteness of hermitian forms, leaving invariant a finite subgroup $G \subset GL(n,\mathbb{C})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I came across this [statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176717/finite-subgroups-of-gln-mathbbc?rq=1) which says that *"A finite subgroup $G$ of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ is conjugate to a subgroup of $U(n)$"*. As trying to understand this, the following question came to me:

---

Assuming I have a finite subgroup $G$ of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ together with an $G$-invariant, non-degenerate hermitian Form $F$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$, then i get that  $G \subset U_F(\mathbb{C}) =\{ X \in GL(n,\mathbb{C})\mid X^tF\overline{X}=F \}$. But how does the finitenes of $G$ imply, that $F$ has to be definite, i.e. that up to conjugation $G \subset U(n,\mathbb{C})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, of course not. But the proof of your statement takes a definite form, and takes its average over the group. By convexity of the bottom eigenvalue, there is a definite invariant form.